# How to clear the app cache when the app starts

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a view [pdf viewers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer) in my app. These get the pdfs from a url and I switch the pdfs often. my problem is, that the pdfs get stored in the cache for a long time. So if I switch the pdfs and you have the old one still in cache, it will show the old one. Is it possible to clear the cache each time when the app starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by checking the  [pdf viewers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer) package, it uses this plugin : [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

First make sure you can use this import.

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
```

..if not , you can install [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) first.

Then try something like this, inside your method.

```
DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

Comment: Thanks fort the hint! It works with this line:   var file = DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();